# jqgrid - empty cell undefined problem in IE

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Im using the following code for formatting date in jqgrid for a cell.

```
function formateDate(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
if(cellvalue!=undefined)
    return changeDateFormat(cellvalue);
else
    return '&nbsp;';}
```

and used `formatter:formateDate` as option for colmodel.

In firefox for empty cells it is showing empty valule but in IE it is showing `undefined//undefined` as its value.

How to remove this value and place empty space in that cell.??

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: Why you have any `undefined` at all in your grid? Do you have jqGrid with local data or don't fill all fields of data in the server response? Why you need to change the format of data with `changeDateFormat`? Why you not just use [formatter:'date'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types)?

Comment: data is coming from the server response and it has all the columns properly. dere are empty columns also coming from server response. the date format in server response will be in mm/dd/yyyy format and i want to display it in dd/mm/yyyy format so i used a custom function.

Comment: The predefined date formatter can change one format of the date to another one. The best format of data to post from the server is yyyy-mm-dd (ISO 8601) data format. With respect of standard predefined date formatter you can covert yyyy-mm-dd or your current mm/dd/yyyy format to dd/mm/yyyy for example.

Answer (score 0):

try using typeof  :

```
function formateDate(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
if(typeof(cellvalue)!='undefined')
    return changeDateFormat(cellvalue);
else
    return '&nbsp;';}
```